# What is swap and how large a swap partition should I create?

Tags: swap

I have a system with 4gb of RAM and Intel i5 processor. I want to know how much memory I should allocate to SWAP. Will allocating more memory help increase the system performance.

In the past i have always allocated 4gb for SWAP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swap is what is used when you run out of RAM.

RAM is fast. SWAP is SLOWWWWWW (being as its mechanical (hard disk) as opposed to ram (purely electronic)).

In the old days, you allocated double the amount of RAM you had to swap. These days its not such a hard and fast rule. 2-4gb is the usual.

---

Related question: [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap)

Comment: This will also depend on the speed of your disk: if you have a Samsung 950 PRO, you can probably afford a bit more on it as swap.