# Stuck on Select drive while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Before, when I was using Ubuntu 12.04, I always installed Ubuntu with Wubi, but this time I was trying install Ubuntu 14.04, I heard that Wubi is no more, so I made an Ubuntu 14.04 installation disk, then rebooted, and tried to install Ubuntu. The problem is I am confused about what to do, how to select the partitions in the Ubuntu installer. Currently I am using a 500GB hard drive, which has 4 partitions:

1. 50GB (Windows 7)
2. 30GB (this is free, wondered to install Ubuntu)
3. 400GB (full with software and multimedia files)
4. 100MB (disk boot)

I don't know how to install, and there is so much confusing language and options, that I am worried, I don't want the wrong partition to get formatted. :(

I only want to install Ubuntu on the second partition (30GB).

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi you need to select "Something Else", which will send you to a dialog where you can see your partitions. Then you just need to click on the 2nd one, the one you want Ubuntu on, and click change, then you can choose Ex4 file system and format partition, (and select the mount point, I just use /) that's where ubuntu will go. Only one issue might be if it asks you to make an EFI partition for boot files, hopefully that won't happen ;-)

Comment: Please open the terminal and run the command `sudo fdisk -l` and then edit your question and add the results of running the command to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start and continue installation

[image]

> select **something else** on this window

[image: select something else in this window]

> now u can see your 500GB and all your drives hard disk
>
> in my case virtual hard disc size is only 8GB capacity it has no partitions in it.

[image]

> **select 30GB drive carefully and delete only that partition** by pressing '-'
> *you can see sizes there so dont worry*

now you will see 30 GB  free space and all of your other drives

[image]

create new **swap area** and **root** partition in free space by selecting **freespace** and pressing +

> first create **swap area** of size twice of your **RAM** size (for eg. 1GB
> for 512MB)

[image]

> put remaining size as **root** partition make sure **Ext4** filesystem is selected
> in my case (8590-1000=7590MB) but **you have to select numbers wrt 30GB and RAM size as I mentioned above.**

[image]

> after that you can see a tick mark on root partition then you an
> continue and finish install

[image]
[image]

Comment: VERY VERY thank you all,  BEST SUPPORT, thanx guys..

Comment: ah sorry, have more question, i dont have much space for swap area, i mean i have 8 gb ram = 8 x 2 = 16 gb i dont have much space, is that necessary to make that space?

Comment: in that case u can also go with small swap area 2-4 GB as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/225759/how-much-do-i-need-for-swap-area