# Mounting Ext4 partition freezes system

Tags: partitioning, mount, nemo

I'm new to Linux. I'm using 13.10 with Cinnamon 2.0 on a Fujitsu A-Series with a Toshiba HDD. The disk has four partitions.

I was copying a few large files from a Windows Phone to a partition when Nemo (and everything else) froze. I shut down, removed the phone and booted.

Now if I attempt to mount the partition the system freezes up.

This is what syslog shows:

```
20:42:39 AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
20:42:39 AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
20:42:51 NetworkManager[772]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted
20:44:51 NetworkManager[772]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted
20:45:45 kernel: [  631.248994] EXT4-fs (sda4): recovery complete
20:45:45 kernel: [  631.280801] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
20:45:45 udisksd[1847]: Mounted /dev/sda4 at /media/trachys/Video on behalf of uid 1000
```

GParted says that there is plenty of unused space on sda4.

Any advice or links appreciated.

**Edit:** umount tells me:

```
trachys@trachys-LIFEBOOK-AH530-HD6:/mnt$ sudo umount -a
umount: /run/user: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
umount: /run/shm: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
umount: /run: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
umount: /dev: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
umount: /: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

Comment: Please come back tomorrow and post your answer on how this was resolved.  You will also be able to accept your own answer to close the thread.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [swap](https://askubuntu.com/a/247528/222824) partition wasn't mounted, something I discovered only after running [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and copying everything to another partition. I can only assume that was the issue, they were large files.