# Dual boot Kubuntu with Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gnome, kubuntu

So I have currently got Ubuntu-Gnome 15.10 installed on my laptop and want to set it up so I can dual boot it with Kubuntu 15.10. I start the Kubuntu installation process but when it gets to the partitioning wizard it doesn't give the option of resizing the partition and installing Kubuntu alongside Ubuntu-Gnome..

Does anybody know why and what I can do to fix this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the manual way: from the live installation open **gparted**. Now you have 2 options.

1. Use a separed /home partition. In this way you can have the same users, file and configuration in two different OS. You can follow [italian instructions from ubuntu-it.org](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Hardware/DispositiviPartizioni/PartizionamentoManuale#home), a good [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cu84OkXzqlI) or the instructions below.
2. Do a normal installation.

Personally I prefer the first option. But note that it's better to do it during the installation, so in Ubuntu Gnome it won't work unless you reinstall it or you follow [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/).

If you chose the *first one*,

- resize the first partition removing the extra space,
- create two partition, one of about 10/15 GB for the system (e.g. for applications) and one for your personal files (e.g. photo, videos)
- open the Kubuntu installer and select **other** when it ask what type of installation you want to do.
- select the partition for the system, click **change...** and, in the box that will appear, select **ext4 with journaling**, in the text input type **/** and press **Ok**. It will ask you if you want to write changes on disk that are not reversible, say **Ok**.
- select the partition for the system, click **change...** and, in the box that will appear, select **ext4 with journaling**, in the text input type **/home** and press **Ok**. It will ask you if you want to write changes on disk that are not reversible, say **Ok**.
- if you have a swap [(what is swap?)](https://askubuntu.com/a/247528/484853) partition, select it, click **change...*** and, in the box that will appear, select **swap** and then click on **Ok**.
- Continue the installation as you would have dove with other type of installation.

If you chose the *second one*,

- resize the first partition removing the extra space,
- create one partition, both for personal files and application (as your current partition)
- open the Kubuntu installer and select **other** when it ask what type of installation you want to do.
- select the partition you created before, click **change...** and, in the box that will appear, select **ext4 with journaling**, in the text input type **/** and press **Ok**. It will ask you if you want to write changes on disk that are not reversible, say **Ok**.
- if you have a swap [(what is swap?)](https://askubuntu.com/a/247528/484853) partition, select it, click **change...*** and, in the box that will appear, select **swap** and then click on **Ok**.
- Continue the installation as you would have dove with other type of installation.

Comment: Thank you very much Giulio I will give that a try and get back to here and let you how it goes :)