# Extend ubuntu swap without reboot and risk

Tags: server, swap

I manage an Ubuntu server part-time in a scientific research laboratory, which has 512G memory and 8G swap space. Recently, we occasionally encounter low-frequency memory shortage, so I plan to expand the swap space. Currently, this server cannot accept any shutdown or accident. I find that they all recommend restarting the device after configuring the swap,

eg: [Increase swap in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264568/increase-swap-in-20-04)

and I'm not sure if I can avoid this

My plan is:

First, find current swap file

```
$ sudo swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swap.img file   8G 7.3G   -2
```

swap off and remove

```
sudo swapoff /swap.img 
sudo rm /swap.img
```

create new swap file

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap.img bs=1M count=92160
```

```
sudo chmod 600 /swap.img
```

create swap

```
sudo mkswap /swap.img
```

enable swap

```
sudo swapon /swap.img
# not reboot
```

Is it ok and safe to do?

Comment: No need to remove "old" swapfile, create an **additional** one (not overwriting!). Linux can work with multiple swapfiles.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/563430/how-to-create-a-swapfile

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, sorry for more question, I am not sure is it necessary to add the new swapfiles to `/etc/fastb` for if I just add not instead the old swap, or the `swapon` will do it automatic

Comment: If you want to have the config over a reboot, you need to add it in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: (however, yes, you can create a second swap file (I do this all the time on servers) and just enable it for that session, without modifying `/etc/fstab`) (to complete the answer)

Comment: Creating a swap file with `dd` will create a discontinuous file, which won't work for swap. Read `man mkswap swapon fstab`.

Comment: @waltinator at least for me (util-linux 2.37.2, Ubuntu jammy 22.04.03), `man swapon` explicitly **recommends** to create swapfiles with `dd` in the "Files with holes" section:
"The most portable solution to create a swap file is to use dd(1) and /dev/zero."