# How much swap do I really need?

Tags: 12.04, hibernate, swap, ram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap)

I have a 4 GB RAM and 300 GB HDD with 8 GB of it as a Swap partition. I'm running 12.04 with hibernate enabled. How much swap do I really need? I don't think I've ever seen my swap percentage use reach even 1%. So how much do I really need?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/a/49138/14356