# Need to give swap space as didn't give it while installation

Tags: swap, disk-management

I did not provide swap space while installing Ubuntu.
How shall i give the swap space now?
I've a multibooted system with win xp and ubuntu.
please help

Comment: Can you add the output of `swapon -s`, and `df`.

Comment: @Mitch
 output of swapon -s: 
'k@Vostro:~$ swapon -s Filename Type Size Used Priority'

output of df: 
'Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on /dev/sda5 20634772 4021872 15564708 21% / udev 500452 4 500448 1% /dev tmpfs 203276 884 202392 1% /run none 5120 0 5120 0% /run/lock none 508184 152 508032 1% /run/shm none 102400 32 102368 1% /run/user'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must to free up some space and make a swap partition using a program like [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/).

After you made a new swap partition, follow this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/33700/147044.

To calculate the size of swap partition, use this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/49138/147044.

Comment: how much space shall i set aside for swap partition?

Comment: @Kattybilly I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a swap file of 512MB, using space from `/dev/sda5` since you're only using up about 8% of it.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=512k sudo mkswap
>   /swapfile

Finish up by activating the swap file:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

To make the swap permanent add it to the fstab file.

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Paste in the following line:

```
 /swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

And finally set up the correct permissions on the swap file:

```
sudo chown root:root /swapfile 
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
```

<sup>Source:DigitalOcean</sup>

Comment: will it affect any data on sda5 which i already have in it and will be safely able to access that data in windows OS too ?
because i saw many suggestions to first make partition first using GParted.

Comment: @Kattybilly Yes! Better to use GParted. Thus, with a little attention you can see exactly what you do.

Comment: It won't, since this will create a swap file.  But its best to create a swap partition instead of a swap file.

Comment: @Mitch so how to go forward after creating a swap partition using GParted ?

Comment: Make sure that you do that from Live CD, since the partition has to be un-mounted.  But once you finish all the needed steps, all you have to do is reboot.  **By the way how much RAM do you have in your machine**?