# I have 4 GB ram.. what should be the perfect swap partition size?

Tags: swap

I heard that swap memory partition should be double the size of ram.. is it true? so I have to keep 8 GB swap space? I'm gonna install Ubuntu gnome 13.04.

Comment: Take a look at [SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq).

Comment: 4 gigabit RAM (or 0.5 GB RAM) is rather low. Did you mean byte (capital B) rather than b (bit) ?

Comment: Already answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap). Hopefully some of the multiple answers there will meet your query.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to have your swap set at a minimum of equal your ram (4gb) but it's recommended to set it at double (8gb).