# Ubuntu 13.04 gets blocked while running VirtualBox

Tags: 13.04, server, virtualbox

I have a fresh installed ubuntu 13.04 and trying to run two virtual maschines on it. It runs for a while and then it gets stuck host and guest (dont respond to ping or ssh). But it doesnt restart. i have to reboot the maschine. syslog doesnt show any sign of error. 
I could use some help to track down why it is and how to get rid of it. Thanks

`<CPU count="4" hotplug="false">`

`<HardwareVirtEx enabled="true" exclusive="true"/>`

`<HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>`

`<HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>`

`<PAE enabled="true"/>`

`<HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>`

`<HardwareVirtForce enabled="false"/>`

`</CPU>`

`<Memory RAMSize="8000" PageFusion="false"/>`

`<HID Pointing="PS2Mouse" Keyboard="PS2Keyboard"/>`

`<HPET enabled="false"/>`

`<Chipset type="PIIX3"/>`

`<StorageController name="IDE" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true"/>`

`<StorageController name="SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="30" useHostIOCache="false" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">`

Edit: It also have the same behavior with vmware player.

Comment: The guests are one ubuntu 12.10 and one windows 2012

Comment: If I got it right you seem you run 2 VMs in parallel with 4 CPU cores and 8GB RAM each. Does your host really have more than 8 CPU cores and more than 16 GB of RAM??

Comment: its a i7 haswell with 32GB RAM

Answer (score 2):

As it may be needed for some virtual machines to perform at the ultimate maximum, and modern CPU's do have an intelligent use of virtualization technology indeed, but for optimum stability of the host we need to leave it at least some resources.

#### Give the host a CPU

- Leave at least **1 core** running **for the host** (i.e. maximum 3 cores for the VMs on a quad-core system).

or

- If we do have to assign all cores to the VMs we need to define an **execution cap** to leave some reserves for the host.

#### Spend some RAM to the host

Virtual Box Manager gives you a warning as soon as you assign more than 50% of available RAM to a VM. It may however be safe to

- leave at least 512 MB (better more) of **RAM for the host** to avoid excessive swapping. Take virtual graphics RAM in account too.

This may considerably increase stability of the host OS. In case we run more than one VM in parallel we may have to further reduce the resources assigned to each as then the CPU cores and the RAM reserved for the VMs sum up.

#### Update

After a fresh installation it may also be a good idea to perform a software and kernel upgrade (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`) for bugfixes, and for the same reason get the newest release of our virtualization software.

Comment: thanks, ill try it out. im considering returning to 12.04 where i copied the machines from. at least i know i workted there.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. i Also formatted the machine and put 12.04. The same problem. I think it might be the extension pack from virtual box. It didnt jam when i didnt have it. Now im removing it and giving it a try.

Answer (score 1):

2 Days without jamming. I think we've got a winner. The **VirtualBox Extension Pack** might be the cause. i just removed it and disabled USB controllers in the vms configuration. So far no jamming. before it used to get stuck every hour.

Tested with:

`Host: Ubuntu 13.04 and 12.04 (same behavior with both)`

`Guest: Ubuntu 12.10 and Win2012`

`CPU: i7-Core 4770`

`RAM 32GB`

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please [file a bug ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker) on virtualbox.org - give instructions on how to reproduce the problem, the physical components of the computer, the host and guest operating system versions. Also include this workaround, so that other users can benefit from it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and tried different solutions found all over the web. But the one worked for me is, reinstalling my Ubuntu OS with allocating the swap space as per the answer here, https://askubuntu.com/a/49138/81288 and after this I'm really got this issue fixed.

Also I'm attaching my VM configuration which is working very smoothly.

[image]

As a tail note, swap space is also needed if you would like to enable "Hibernate" option for your Ubuntu machine.