# Host completely freezes when I spawn a Vm on virtualbox

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, kubuntu, freeze

Over my Kubuntu 16.04 LTS machine I try to spawn a VM using virtualbox but the whole ui comletely freezes. Few days before with same OS over my laptop I manage to spaawn vms.

My machine has 16GB ram and 16GB swap so swap does not seem to be an issue according to [Ubuntu freezes when starting virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675458/ubuntu-freezes-when-starting-virtualbox)

I also tried to reinstall both `virtualbox` & `virtualbox-dkms` packages without any noticable change towards to a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on: [VirtualBox 5.0.40 crashes the whole host since update to kernel 4.13.0-26-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994621/virtualbox-5-0-40-crashes-the-whole-host-since-update-to-kernel-4-13-0-26-generi)

Check the virtualbox version with the command:

```
apt-cache policy `dpkg -S VirtualBox | head -n1 | sed -e 's/://g' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Ans the kernel version with the command:

```
 uname -r
```

There is a posibility an unsupported version of virtualbox form the kernel. I would suggest using virtualbox 5.2 version or later. Please follow the link above in order to look for instructions on how to install it.

In my case when that happened I had the `4.13.0-26-generic` kernel and virtualbox version `5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2`.

Comment: I had the same problem than Dimitrios, and indeed that solved it.

Comment: i completely uninstall virtualbox and still when I use the commands above, it says: 4.13.0-36-generic
what should i do??

Comment: Is not the kernel that should change but the virtualbox version. In other words install the latest virtualbox ;) If you have probs with that then follow the steps  in the link and check if your problems have been solved.