# Why does Ubuntu install default to minimum swap partition size?

Tags: installation, swap

When installing Ubuntu unless you do a manual partition, you get roughly and x+.5 MB swap space, where x is the amount of ram present. At least this has been my experience. I that official Ubuntu documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) recommends having 2x ram for the swap partition and indicates that x is the minimum why aren't we defaulting to larger swap sizes, especially considering the relatively low expense of storage?

Answer (score 0):

Relatively low price of storage? Pfft. I have 24GB of RAM and 120GB of SSD. I'd strongly mind if I lost 48GB of SSD to swap.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap/49130#49130) deals with the high-RAM views in the industry. Basically, if you have tons of RAM, it's unlikely you're going to need tons of swap unless you're dealing with very specific workloads that could force things into swap.

RAM+.5GB simply ensures there's more than enough to push all of RAM into swap at hibernate without too much of a fight. That should cover most behaviours.

If you're on a low-RAM system, you'll probably need more.

Comment: Yes, relatively low cost. Here's a link for a 256 GB pen drive:

Comment: Sorry: Here's a link for a 256 GB pen drive:http://www.amazon.com/Flash-Drives-256gb-Memory-Sticks/dp/B00B4W34T2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1386269280&sr=8-1&keywords=256+gb+flash+drive, I'd suggest looking into it if 24 GB is such a disaster for you. I understand that your HD is of the fancy type, but when I got my machine I think it cost me 30 bucks to go from 1TB to 2TB and the going rate on 120 GB SDD looks to be about 90 bucks... which isn't that much. So yes, relatively inexpensive.  Pfft.

Comment: I'm not taking about flash memory, though. I'm taking about high quality MLC.