# Forgot to add swap memory during installation

Tags: swap, memory-usage

In my ignorance I didn't add swap memory to my install. So my question is, can I work without it and if not how can I add it to my existing install?

Love to get some feedback!

Comment: This may also be of interest: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/do-i-need-a-swap-sized-double-of-the-amount-of-ram

Answer (score 2):

> Can i work whitout swap?

It depends on your RAM size.If your RAM size is too low, you have to create swap otherwise you won't.

See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_much_swap_do_I_need.3F) page for how much swap space do you really need, according to you RAM size.

> How can i add it to my excisting install?

You can create a new swap partition using Gparted Utility.And don't forget to create a new fstab entry for your created swap partition.See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_more_swap.3F) page for how to create swap partition and add it to the existing Ubuntu installation.