# Dual boot ubuntu 14 .04LTS

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-xp

I'm currently using Windows Xp need to keep it on and install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can I keep both OS on one HDD dual boot?I wouldn't with virtual box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Back Up Your Data.
2 - Make a space. 'by delete a partition or something you can do that from the Ubuntu installation ' 
3 - Boot from live CD/DVD/USB. 'if it doesn't boot auto make it boot from the cd 1st'
4 - Proceed with installation until you gets in Installation Type.
5 - chose something elese then make a partition as 
click on the freespace'under the windows parts''
a type : Primary.
b size : your size - 1000 MB .'you need 1000 Mb for the swap partition 1k Mb is just an example'
c use as :ext4.
d mount point chose : / .
 click ok
now click again on the free space '1000 MB you should know how much you need for swap part from this link https://askubuntu.com/a/49130/299605'
a type : logical
b use as : swap area 
 click ok 
click install now