# Create Swap for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: swap

I'm using 2 GB RAM I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS how much swap do I need to create?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please modify your question to add additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is varying opinion on what the size of the swap should be - here are the Example Scenarios provided in the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq):

```
RAM(MB) No hibernation  With Hibernation        Absolute maximum
 256     256              512                     512
 512     512             1024                    1024
1024    1024             2048                    2048

RAM(GB) No hibernation  With Hibernation        Absolute maximum
  1      1                2                       2
  2      1                3                       4
  3      2                5                       6
  4      2                6                       8
  5      2                7                      10
  6      2                8                      12
  8      3               11                      16
 12      3               15                      24
 16      4               20                      32
 24      5               29                      48
 32      6               38                      64
 64      8               72                     128
128     11              139                     256
```

Here also a table from the [Fedora 64bit docs](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Installation_Guide/s2-diskpartrecommend-x86.html#idm219179287040)):

[image: For <2GB, it recommends the swap should be '3 times the amount of RAM' in size.]

This mainly depends if you need want to hibernate or not - you need more as it saves the state of the system from the RAM to the swap.

Note swap may slow things down if swappiness is not configured correctly - you can read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness) to find out how to do it.

If you need to increase the size of (or create) swap space, there are a few nice answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space).

Comment: The Ubuntu one is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq - it doesn't have a neat table, but then again, I prefer text to images.

Answer (score 1):

For small RAM sizes like 1 or 2 or 3 GB its better to create a swap partition with double the size of RAM. eg: 4GB in your case. For rams higher like 8 GB swap partition of 2 GB will be sufficient.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap Personally i HAVE 2gb OF ram in this machine and 1GB of swap and have never run out. The double RAM Swap idea is a myth perpetuated by windows due to it's poor memory management. 'nix systems are much more RAM efficient. That being said a lot depends on what you are doing with the system. Video editing requires more ram than browsing the web, playing youtube videos and checking your email.

Comment: @Elder Geek- yes seems true but hibernation do requires high swap space.

Comment: That's a good point. I never use it. I turn things off when I'm not using them.

Comment: @Elder Geek- what would be the minimum swap space for hibernation

Comment: @Sudheer how I can create swap in currently installed drive or root?

Comment: @Sudheer As I never use it, My best guess in this instance would be 3GB

Comment: @user73898 you should create a separate partition for swap.

Comment: @Elder Geek- I never used it but, want to try it sometime. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: @Sudheer Not true, you can create a swap file on an existing partition.

Comment: @user73898 That's a different question. Look here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I have 12 Gb RAM - and I don't have any swap. I think of my RAM as if I had 8 Gb RAM and 4 Gb of fast swap :) In fact required swap depends on the computer usage. I don't think that having swap is really good idea in era when memory is one of the most cheepest pc components.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I always make my swap 512 MB, just to have some wiggle room. If the OS starts using a lot of swap, you *really* need more RAM. (And if getting more RAM is not an option, *then* you can consider having more swap, it's better than nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

## **4GB.**

Without additional information we can't be specific, so I'm erring on the larger side: 4GB is probably more than you need, and disk space is cheap.