# Installing 14.04.1-first time user. What is Install Type window for-to format and select partition, or to create swap area?

Tags: partitioning, swap

While installing at install type window I entered ext4 and / or root as mount point.  I also checked format drive.  After clicking install now I get a message that I have no swap partition.  Should I go ahead with install and then use gparted to create a swap partition or do it before I install?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/q/49109/158442 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation - I'd say ditch swap if you have plenty of RAM and won't hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

[Swap space](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) is essentially disk space that gets used as RAM when your computer is running low on memory.

It's not essential to have swap space, but you could run into problems if you don't have any, and most of your RAM is being used.

Generally, unless you don't have a reason not to, you should create swap space. Follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_much_swap_do_I_need.3F) for choosing the amount - as a rule of thumb, create at least as much swap as you have RAM.

It doesn't matter if you do it before or after the installation. However, if you plan to do it after the install, be sure to leave enough space to create the swap partition - otherwise, you'll have to shrink your current partition from a live USB/CD.