# GParted does not show free space partitioned with Windows

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted

This is my third failed attempt at dual booting windows 8.1 and Ubuntu (14.04 twice, and now 15.04). My computer is a Gigabyte Aorus X3 plus V3. When I tried to install Ubuntu using the 'something else' option (as it does not detect windows 8.1) it showed me that I had only 1Mb of free space, even though I had shrunk the windows partition by roughly 250Gb. I read on another ticket that this may be because of something that windows does to the free space with it's partition editor without warning. I extended my windows volume back to it's original size. What do I do now? How do I create space for Ubuntu without using windows partition editing tools?

Comment: Do you mean `gparted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Boot from Ubuntu install media.
- Select <kbd>Try Ubuntu without installing</kbd>.
- Open <kbd>GParted</kbd> (Partitioning tool).
- Reduce the Windows partition.
- Create a partition for Ubuntu (size that fits your needs).
- Create a swap partition (size minimum matching RAM).
- On the desktop click <kbd>Install Ubuntu</kbd>.
- Choose <kbd>Something else</kbd>.
- Select the partition you created for Ubuntu before.

Comment: Swap size does not necessarily need to be as big as the installed RAM. One should decide that based on the installed RAM size *and* the expected system usage. Please read http://askubuntu.com/q/49109/367990

Comment: @ByteCommander : There are a lot of different opinions regarding the amount of swap space, such as about the reboot necessity topic. So as always, I keep recommending : Better stay on the safe side ! The disk capacity on modern hardware in most of the cases is large enough, so it really doesn't matter too much at all. Thank you for your hint anyway ! :)