# How much swap memory should i have if i have 2 GB of ram?

Tags: kubuntu, swap, memory-usage

I'll be basically doing programming and stuff.

Comment: Anywhere between 2 to 4 GB should be OK, but it's completely upto you as to how much you should allocate.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap) answer will help.

Comment: Normally your system will get soooo slow once it has to swap out even only 2GB that it's barely usable any more, so you would go exit some applications anyway. So 2GB plus a bit extra to be safe should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

The standard recommendation for swap space is double your RAM, but if you have 4 GB RAM or more, you can usually get away with less swap space.  For instance, I recently upgraded my desktop machine from 4 GB to 8 GB RAM, and didn't bother changing the size of my swap space -- it's still equal to my RAM, so it's unlikely I'll overrun it.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 GB RAM you should have at least 2 GB swap memory or more but ideally it should be double of your RAM (in this case 4 GB)