# ubuntu 18.04 restarts after shutting down

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, reboot

This appears to be a common symptom, for a myriad of underlying causes -- but none of the online solutions I tried worked.  I have a system76 laptop (galago ultrapro).  Since a few days (after an upgrade perhaps?), my machine started to reboot after I poweroff (either graphically or `poweroff`).

Some notes:

- I do not have wake up on LAN/WLAN enabled (`sudo ethtool wlp3s0` shows me no wake on lan settings)
- I have tried a number of parameters in `/etc/default/grub`, such as `acpi=force` and `acpi=noirq`.  The latter (`noirq`) seemed to work in that it shut down the machine permanently, but disabled my laptop's keyboard (but not my mouse, that was a fun hour).  So I had to revert.
- I have tried the other fixes mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139612/debian-wheezy-rebooting-instead-of-powering-off), but none of them worked for me.

**An interesting find: if I take out the power cable (laptop is on battery), the laptop always powers down without reboot (expected behaviour).  It is only when the laptop is connected to power that this rebooting behaviour occurs (frequently, but not always).**  I have tried other power outlets (just in case), and the same reboot-after-shutdown  happens, so the problem persists.

Can you help me diagnose and fix the problem please?

The output of `dmesg | grep -i acpi` as requested.  This is after one of the mysterious reboots.

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cbd21000-0x00000000cbd27fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000db8db000-0x00000000dba0ffff] ACPI NVS
[    0.033110] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.033114] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F0490 000024 (v02 ALASKA)
[    0.033117] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000DB9E3080 00007C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.033124] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000DB9EFB80 00010C (v05 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.033130] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000DB9E3190 00C9EA (v02 ALASKA A M I    00000024 INTL 20091112)
[    0.033133] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000DBA0E080 000040
[    0.033136] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000DB9EFC90 000092 (v03 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.033139] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000DB9EFD28 000044 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.033142] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB9EFD70 0015C2 (v01 TrmRef PtidDevc 00001000 INTL 20091112)
[    0.033145] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB9F1338 0004F7 (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.033148] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB9F1830 000AD8 (v01 PmRef  CpuPm    00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.033151] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000DB9F2308 00003C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 MSFT 00000097)
[    0.033154] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000DB9F2348 000038 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI. 00000005)
[    0.033157] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB9F2380 000315 (v01 SataRe SataTabl 00001000 INTL 20091112)
[    0.033161] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB9F2698 001917 (v01 SaSsdt SaSsdt   00003000 INTL 20091112)
[    0.033164] ACPI: DMAR 0x00000000DB9F3FB0 0000B8 (v01 INTEL  HSW      00000001 INTL 00000001)
[    0.033173] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.098719] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x1808
[    0.098721] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.098729] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.098742] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.098743] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.098745] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.098746] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.098748] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.098750] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a701 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.184954] ACPI: Core revision 20190703
[    0.291091] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xcbd21000-0xcbd27fff] (28672 bytes)
[    0.291091] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xdb8db000-0xdba0ffff] (1265664 bytes)
[    0.291091] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    0.291091] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.291091] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.297204] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.297205] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.297206] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.297207] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.297208] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.297209] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.297210] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.310226] ACPI: 6 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.312008] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.312671] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.312671] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8A108D11E400 0003D3 (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20051117)
[    0.313563] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.313570] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8A108D054800 0005AA (v01 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.314980] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.314984] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8A108CC64200 000119 (v01 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.319018] ACPI: EC: EC started
[    0.319018] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[    1.181152] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC__: Used as first EC
[    1.181154] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC__: GPE=0x17, EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    1.181156] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC__: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions
[    1.181156] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    1.181190] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    1.181192] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    1.181227] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    1.181574] ACPI: Enabled 7 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
[    1.192898] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-3e])
[    1.192905] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
[    1.193205] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME]
[    1.193448] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [AER PCIeCapability LTR]
[    1.193449] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
[    1.196845] acpiphp: Slot [1] registered
[    1.198785] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    1.198864] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 *4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15)
[    1.198939] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
[    1.199015] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
[    1.199090] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 *5 6 10 11 12 14 15)
[    1.199165] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[    1.199241] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs *3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15)
[    1.199317] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    1.199772] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[    1.199779] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[    1.199785] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC__: GPE=0x17, EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    1.199787] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC__: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions and events
[    1.199861] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    1.199861] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    1.219689] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    1.219816] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active)
[    1.220253] system 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    1.220279] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    1.220350] system 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT3f0d PNP0c02 (active)
[    1.220384] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    1.220503] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs SYN1213 PNP0f13 (active)
[    1.220568] system 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    1.221061] system 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    1.221405] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
[    1.227356] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
[    1.949294] ACPI: AC Adapter [AC] (on-line)
[    1.949372] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    1.949409] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    1.949445] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    1.949483] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    1.950060] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ0] (14 C)
[    1.950732] battery: ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    3.947861] system76_acpi: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.947878] system76_acpi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    5.264311] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001800-0x000000000000187F (\PMIO) (20190703/utaddress-213)
[    5.264318] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    5.264321] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C40-0x0000000000001C4F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20190703/utaddress-213)
[    5.264325] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    5.264326] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20190703/utaddress-213)
[    5.264330] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20190703/utaddress-213)
[    5.264333] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    5.264334] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20190703/utaddress-213)
[    5.264338] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20190703/utaddress-213)
[    5.264342] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    5.443842] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
```

Comment: An interesting finding (perhaps).  When the laptop is on battery (whatever is left of it) it always shuts down correctly; without reboot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `dmesg | grep -i acpi` and have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1200540/968501)

Comment: Edited as requested.

Comment: As expected `ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it` is present in the output. Try the suggestions in the linked answer in my comment above. This is the same case.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your wifi card? Then check if this is still a problem?

Comment: @ognjen Yes I tried disabling the wifi before switching off.  The same behaviour (rebooting) persists.

Comment: Please add the note about shutdown on battery in the OP, not as a comment

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio done, as requested.
@Raffa I have tried `pcie_aspm=off` and `pcie_aspm=force` in `/etc/default/grub` (and `sudo update-grub`), to no avail.

Comment: What about the suggestions?

Comment: None of them worked (or made a difference) unfortunately.

Comment: @MalteseUnderdog, when you said that it works without power plug. I suspect a PNP (like USB, Firewire,..) device is source of the issue. Could you add output of `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` . Here few things to try: (1) Unplug all external devices try reboot (2) Check which port stay on with power plugged after using emergency off (long press on power button) (3) Check in the BIOS/UEFI, disable USB power share  if you have it, I don't want ask you test by disabling devices because it is hard to reset BIOS to default on laptops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going into the grub menu by turning your computer on and hold shift down...then select advance....then go down one level to recovery mode.There you can either choose check system to see what's wrong and/or choose repair broken packages. That might help to solve the problem,good luck! https://drive.google.com/open?id=12YI4bhQgeC7McHsfdOTdE0qRQELK-b-F

Comment: I have had no success with this (no broken packages)

Answer (score 0):

Your question:**Can you help me diagnose and fix the problem please?**

This answer aims only at the second point, which I guess is more important.

Use command `shutdown` instead of `poweroff`. 
You could check the [various options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/shutdown.8.html) for `shutdown`.
In particular, try `shutdown -P`.
I have seen conflicting information about the difference between the two commands, so please post feedback.

See also

1. [What's the difference between poweroff and halt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205464/whats-the-difference-between-poweroff-and-halt) and links there.
2. [Poweroff vs. shutdown now](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/39pj5d/poweroff_vs_shutdown_now/)

Comment: if OP does it graphically, it is `shutdown` and not `poweroff`