# System freeze when idle

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell

On a Dell Latitude 5510 I get constant system freeze when idle. If I leave the laptop for a couple of minutes doing nothing on it, when i come back everything is frozen. No mouse,keyboard,no input accepted. Only solution is reboot.
BIOS is up to date, latest kernel, latest updates,using GNOME,suspended options are disabled.
Using Intel CPU,Intel integrated graphics, NVMe SSD.

Please let me know if other info is required, as this is getting really annoying and I could not found any solution.

**UPDATE:**
Runned memtest,no errors found

also getting bellow errors:

```
tpm tpm0: tpm_try_transmit: send(): error -5
tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
```

Output from `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` on wireless has these additional lines as on wired connection:

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Output from `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` on wired connection:

```
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
usb: port power management may be unreliable
i8042: Warning: Keylock active
platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:03: WQBC data block query control method not found
acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:05: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:06: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:07: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Accelerometer lis3lv02d is present on SMBus but its address is unknown, skipping registration
i2c_hid i2c-DELL09A1:00: i2c-DELL09A1:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
i2c_hid i2c-DELL09A1:00: i2c-DELL09A1:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
Started bpfilter
systemd-journald[322]: File /var/log/journal/009ee102156a46ea89398cda32e51235/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: Failed to reset PPM! Trying again..
thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
```

Output from `journalctl -b-1 -g failed`

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2021-02-16 17:25:28 EET, end at Wed 2021-02-17 09:51:30 EET. --
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: Failed to reset PPM! Trying again..
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 kernel: thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 thermald[730]: [WARN]sysfs open failed
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 udisksd[731]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 udisksd[731]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
feb 17 09:09:14 sergiu-Latitude-5510 NetworkManager[688]: <warn>  [1613545754.3767] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
feb 17 09:09:14 sergiu-Latitude-5510 NetworkManager[688]: <warn>  [1613545754.6108] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
feb 17 09:09:14 sergiu-Latitude-5510 bluetoothd[758]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 bluetoothd[758]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-media-keys[1352]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:hibernate
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-media-keys[1352]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-random
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-media-keys[1352]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:rfkill
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-media-keys[1352]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
feb 17 09:09:17 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:17 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:17 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:17 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:17 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:19 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1122]: dbus-daemon[1122]: [session uid=121 pid=1122] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:19 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:19 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:19 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:19 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:22 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1186]: Warning: Failed to start gsd-xsettings
feb 17 09:09:26 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1694]: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
feb 17 09:09:27 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1591]: gnome-session-x11@ubuntu.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
feb 17 09:09:27 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1591]: gnome-session.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
feb 17 09:09:27 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1591]: gnome-session@gnome-initial-setup.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
feb 17 09:09:27 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1591]: gnome-session@gnome-login.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
feb 17 09:09:27 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1591]: gnome-session-x11.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
feb 17 09:09:27 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1591]: gnome-session@ubuntu.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
feb 17 09:09:27 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1591]: gnome-session-failed.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1186]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 66 failed: Permission denied
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1186]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 48 failed: Permission denied
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-media-keys[1956]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:rfkill
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-media-keys[1956]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-media-keys[1956]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:hibernate
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-media-keys[1956]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-random
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 colord[1451]: failed to get session [pid 1951]: No data available
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 colord[1451]: failed to get session [pid 1951]: No data available
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1186]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 66 failed: Permission denied
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1186]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 48 failed: Permission denied
feb 17 09:09:29 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-color[1951]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Dell_Inc__DELL_E2418HN_K3VT995Q0RHB_gdm_121
feb 17 09:09:29 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-color[1951]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_BOE_gdm_121
feb 17 09:09:29 sergiu-Latitude-5510 org.freedesktop.FileManager1[2088]: Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
feb 17 09:09:29 sergiu-Latitude-5510 dbus-daemon[1608]: [session uid=1000 pid=1608] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.FileManager1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:11:44 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1834]: meta_display_get_monitor_in_fullscreen: assertion 'monitor >= 0 && monitor < n_logical_monitors' failed
feb 17 09:11:44 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1834]: meta_monitor_manager_get_logical_monitor_from_number: assertion '(unsigned int) number < g_list_length (manager->logical_monitors)' failed
feb 17 09:11:44 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1834]: meta_workspace_get_work_area_for_monitor: assertion 'logical_monitor != NULL' failed
feb 17 09:12:20 sergiu-Latitude-5510 NetworkManager[688]: <info>  [1613545940.9272] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'supplicant-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
feb 17 09:15:03 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-udevd[3601]: regulatory.0: Process '/sbin/crda' failed with exit code 234.
feb 17 09:15:24 sergiu-Latitude-5510 snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop[2718]: Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/518/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Error opening file /snap/snap-store/518/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
feb 17 09:15:24 sergiu-Latitude-5510 snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop[2718]: Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/518/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Error opening file /snap/snap-store/518/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
```

Output from `journalctl -b-1 -g error`

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2021-02-16 17:25:28 EET, end at Wed 2021-02-17 09:51:30 EET. --
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 kernel: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p4): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
feb 17 09:09:13 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
feb 17 09:09:14 sergiu-Latitude-5510 NetworkManager[688]: <warn>  [1613545754.3767] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-session-binary[1136]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:15 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-session[1136]: gnome-session-binary[1136]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1186]: Error setting property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Blocked: Blocked through rfkill (g-io-error-quark, 36)
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1186]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:16 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:17 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:17 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:17 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:17 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:19 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:19 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:19 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:19 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gsd-sharing[1323]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
feb 17 09:09:21 sergiu-Latitude-5510 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1570]: > Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym Invalid
feb 17 09:09:21 sergiu-Latitude-5510 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1570]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
feb 17 09:09:26 sergiu-Latitude-5510 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1694]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
feb 17 09:09:27 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-session-c[1813]: Error creating FIFO: File exists
feb 17 09:09:28 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1834]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
feb 17 09:09:29 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1834]: Error connecting to Nautilus
feb 17 09:09:29 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:09:29 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:09:30 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:09:30 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:09:30 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:09:30 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:09:30 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:09:30 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:09:39 sergiu-Latitude-5510 tracker-miner-f[1112]: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
feb 17 09:09:39 sergiu-Latitude-5510 tracker-miner-f[1112]: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
feb 17 09:09:39 sergiu-Latitude-5510 tracker-miner-f[1112]: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
feb 17 09:11:11 sergiu-Latitude-5510 gnome-shell[1834]: JS ERROR: TypeError: area is null
                                                    padArea@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1101:9
                                                    _updateWindowPositions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1334:20
                                                    _realRecalculateWindowPositions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1311:14
                                                    _recalculateWindowPositions/this._positionWindowsId<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1286:18
feb 17 09:11:21 sergiu-Latitude-5510 org.gnome.tweaks.desktop[2283]: WARNING : Error loading desktopfile: /home/sergiu/.config/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop
feb 17 09:12:30 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:12:30 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:14:35 sergiu-Latitude-5510 fwupd[2922]: ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/esys_context.c:69:Esys_Initialize() Initialize default tcti. ErrorCode (0x000a000a)
feb 17 09:14:38 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:15:24 sergiu-Latitude-5510 snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop[2718]: Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/518/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Error opening file /snap/snap-store/518/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
feb 17 09:15:24 sergiu-Latitude-5510 snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop[2718]: Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/518/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Error opening file /snap/snap-store/518/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
feb 17 09:15:30 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
feb 17 09:16:33 sergiu-Latitude-5510 systemd-resolved[633]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would a suspend issue exist on an installed OS but not its Live Disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217974/why-would-a-suspend-issue-exist-on-an-installed-os-but-not-its-live-disk)

Comment: This is related as well: [How to find acpi drivers for specific acpi device / Solving kernel suspend bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198969/how-to-find-acpi-drivers-for-specific-acpi-device-solving-kernel-suspend-bug)

Comment: Thx for the input, I added `pcie_aspm=force` in grub, but still getting freezes, even when I am working on laptop. Any other ideas what to check?

Comment: Other than suggestions in the above linked posts....I am afraid not... it is what it is, sorry. If BIOS update doesn't fix it then probably disable suspend for the time being.

Comment: Suspend it's disable with `sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`, i hope is the right way to do it.

Comment: Not the usual way but if it works for you why not? you can *unmask* those services anytime later. The usual way is via power options in **settings** and in [tweaks tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-closelid.html.en)

Comment: Closed as unable to reproduce as OP has solved the issue with replacement RAM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the freezing issue was caused by a memory module.
I added a second memory module in an authorized service center after i bought the laptop. We replaced that module and the issue is gone, although all hardware diagnostics were passed.

Answer (score -1):

If screen freezes, the easiest way to recover (apart from reboot) is to restart desktop manager.

1. Press CTRL+ALT+F4 ( this will enter in single user mode (terminal).
2. Then login with user id and password
3. Then run the following:

   sudo service lightdm restart