# Ubuntu 16.04, I need to increase swap space?

Tags: 16.04, swap

Ubuntu 16.04
16GB RAM.

How can i increase swap memory in my case?
And how many GB i have to add?
[image]

Comment: What makes you think you need more swap? Currently it looks good to me, I mean, you have ~3GB free RAM.

Comment: just because I saw that virtual memory is almost full. However, if I create a swap file does not make the situation worse?

Answer (score 0):

About the amount of swap you need, see this discussion:
[I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap)
It highly depends on your usage of the machine.

About how to increase swap memory:
you can use GParted and see from there if you have some unallocated partition that you can use.
If this is not the case, you can also use a swap file.
See here for details:
[How to increase swap space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space?rq=1)

Comment: See other duplicate...  **;-)**