# How to resize root partition on a live system?

Tags: root, resize

I'm a Linux beginner and I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a usb stick and went with manual partitioning.

At install, I thought that 20GB would be enough for root, and allocated first 20GB to root, then 30 GB swap and then the rest to /home.

Now the OS is telling me it's low on disk space on root but I don't know what can fill it up really as 20GB for an OS without the user's home should be plenty. Unfortunately I can't seem to see what's filling up root as the GUI utilities (Disk Usage Analyzer) provide little insight.

I tried to shrink the /home via Disks and I can't. Neither the swap. So the question is:

How can I shrink any of the /swap or /home so that to make free space to enlarge the root on a live system? I can't boot into live environment because I don't have physical access to the machine, only remote! Please don't tell me I can't do this without a reboot or a boot into a live USB! I come from macOS world and there is no problem resizing a partition on a live system.

Here are some screenshots if it helps!

[image: Disk Usage Analyzer reports this!]

[image: fdisk -l][image: Disks]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: 30 GB swap seems excessive. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap) for more.

Comment: I understand this is possible with LVM, but you did not install with LVM.

Comment: @user68186 no because it seems all solutions require unmounting the partition you wish to modify and since unmounting home is not an option, it seems the only solution is to shrink it via live usb

Comment: Always use Live USB to resize system and `/home` partitions.